# Find documents whose array field contain some subsets in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

The "users" collection has documents with an array field.

Example documents:

```
{
    "_id" :1001,
    "properties" : ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I"]
}
{
    "_id" : 1002,
    "properties" : ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
}
```

How can I build a query to get the documents which follow the next condition?
Get only the documents that have the properties:

```
[ "3" AND ("A" OR "1") AND ("B" OR "2") ]
```

or in other way:

```
    "3" AND "A" AND "B"
OR
    "3" AND "A" AND "2"
OR
    "3" AND "1" AND "B"
OR
    "3" AND "1" AND "2"
```

In the previous example, the query has to result only the document:

```
{
    "_id" : 1002,
    "properties" : ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]
}
```

The collection has 4 million documents. The document array "properties" field has average length of 15 elements. The query I am looking for must have a good performance in this quite a big collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stephan's answer is ok. Other ways to achieve the result using [$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values)  and [$all](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) operators:

```
db.users.find(
    {
    $and:[
        {"properties":"3"},
        {"properties" : {$in: ["A", "1"]}},
        {"properties" : {$in: ["B", "2"]}}
    ]
    }
);
```

(translation of your first description of the subset)

And

```
db.users.find(
    {
       $or: [
        {"properties" : {$all: ["3", "A", "B"]}},
        {"properties" : {$all: ["3", "A", "2"]}},
        {"properties" : {$all: ["3", "1", "B"]}},
        {"properties" : {$all: ["3", "1", "2"]}}
    ]
    }
);
```

(translation of your second description of the subset)

I'm afraid I can't tell which one will ensure the best performance. I hope that you have and index on `properties`.

You may try the queries on a smaller collection with [explain](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) to see the execution plan

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
db.users.find(
    {
        $or: [
            {$and: [{ "properties": "3" }, { "properties": "A" }, { "properties": "B" }]},
            {$and: [{ "properties": "3" }, { "properties": "A" }, { "properties": "2" }]},
            {$and: [{ "properties": "3" }, { "properties": "1" }, { "properties": "B" }]},
            {$and: [{ "properties": "3" }, { "properties": "1" }, { "properties": "2" }]}
        ]
    }
);
```

or

```
db.users.find(
    {
        $and: [
            {"properties": "3" },
            {$or: [ { "properties": "A" }, { "properties": "1" } ]},
            {$or: [ { "properties": "B" }, { "properties": "2" } ]}
        ]
    }
);
```